# find_and_modify with upsert using Python-EVE

Tags: python, rest, pymongo, eve

There is common use case when you need update or insert. For instance:

```
 obj = db['data'].find_and_modify(
        {
            'Name': data['Name'],
            'SourcePage': data['SourcePage'],
        },
        data,
        upsert=True
    )
```

Of course can split this request into `GET` and then `PATCH` or `INSERT` **but maybe there is better way?**

P.S. eve provides some nice features like document versions and meta data (_created, _updated etc.)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`upsert` support is now part of the [upcoming release](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/commit/1e1f936ed38fc18ff800f40e90ab6807ab30e4b6).

One doesn't have to do anything different.  The feature is "turned on" by default. So if a user tries to `PUT` an item that does not exist, a new item will be created. The `id` field sent in the payload is ignored.

If a user does not want this feature, the user needs to explicitly set `UPSERT_ON_PUT` to `False`. Now, the user gets the "old" behaviour back. i.e when the user tries to `PUT` non-existing item, `404` is returned.

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying to find that answer for over an hr.

Comment: hey Vaze, even when setting UPSERT_ON_PUT to TRUE, im still getting a 404. what should be the url be when sending a PUT request on an non-existent item?